# Collect Request and sent it in Bulk

Tags: asp.net-web-api

I'm using ASP.Net WebAPI. What I'm trying to achieve is to gathers all Request in a `List<T>`, and sent it by bulk to somewhere else. Basically my requirement is to sent it by bulk only when the list reaches some number or some period of time.

Since `List<T>` is not a thread safe, so I assume I must use `ConcurrentBag<T>`. But how do I get the instance of previous created Bag?

Comment: your service is a single instance, why not create a member in your controller of all the requests and each time save the incoming request to that list. Once list reaches your threshold, send all the requests by bulk.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class MyController : ApiController
{
 private IList<object> _requests;

 public MyController(){
  _requests = new List<object>();
}

public void Post()
{
  if (_requests.Count < SomeCounter)
    _requests.Add(Request);
  else
  ...Send Bulk..

}
}
```